# What does clojure 'val' return this value?

Tags: clojure

I'm just starting to learn clojure and have been reading some simple examples and then doing my best to rtfm for concepts.

However I'm a bit confused by what `val` is doing in the example below. This has been taken from the Clojure doc examples for [val](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/val).

```
(first {:one :two}) ;; => [:one :two]
```

Here, a `hash-map` with a key of `:one` and a value of `:two` is being passed to `first`. Behind the scenes, Clojure converts this `hash-map` to a `sequence` of `vectors`. Since there is only one `vector` in this `sequence`, it returns `[:one :two]`.

```
(val (first {:one :two})) ;; => :two
(val [:one :two]) ;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
(val {:one :two}) ;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
```

If I try to call `val` on a (I think) a `hash-map` (I realize it's actually a "persistent array map"), I get the exception as seen above.

I'm also confused by the following:

```
(first {:one :two}) ;; # => [:one :two]  (this is a vector right?)
(val [:one :two]) ;; # => ClassCastException (why doesn't this give back the same result as the example above?)
```

Why can't I just plug the result of `(first {:one :two})` into `val` and get the same result?

---

Additionally, another example listed on the page is the following:

```
(map val {:a 1 :b 2}) ;; => (1 2)
```

Here's how I read the line. Take the `array-map` `{:a 1 :b 2}`. For each key-value pair, call `val` on the pair to return the value. Return a `sequence` from the resulting calls to `map`. Is this the correct way to read the problem?

As always, thanks for any and all help.

Comment: A map entry is a vector, but not all vectors are map entries. `val` only works on map entries.

Comment: ... to wit, `(type (first {:one :two}))` => `clojure.lang.MapEntry`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a sequence of a map produces `MapEntry` values as you've noted, which look like and can be compared with vectors

```
user=> (= (first {:a 1 :b 2}) [:a 1])
true
```

but aren't the same class

```
user=> (= (class (first {:a 1 :b 2})) (class [:a 1]))
false
```

So although the output on the repl of `(first {:a 1})` looks like a vector, it isn't, it's a `MapEntry`, so it can be passed to `val`, but the vector `[:a 1]` cannot, hence the class cast exception.

Your reading of what map is doing is correct at a high level, a little more specific might be "For each entry in the sequence from {:a 1 :b 2} (which are MapEntry values) call the function val on each item (a MapEntry), and generate a sequence from the results".

This will explain why something like

```
user=> (map val '([:a 1] [:b 2]))
```

will cause the same `ClassCastException`s as the sequence generates `Vector` elements, not `MapEntry` elements.

Answer (score 6):

`val` returns value of a map entry, not a map.

`(first {:one :two})` return the first map entry (although it appears to be just a vec)

`(map val {:one :two})` return the value of every entry, and is equivalent to `(vals {:one :two})`

Answer (score 3):

```
(first {:one :two}) ;; # => [:one :two]  (this is a vector right? No, it's not.)
```

`[:one :two]` in this case is a `MapEntry`, not a vector.